Unable to boot in QEMU the raspberrypi3-64 image built in Yocto
I'm trying to boot raspberrypi image using QEMU, but I need my custom Image.
I followed all instructions in Yocto (scarthgap) (I've been using Yocto for some time so let's say I know what I'm doing) but I'm not able to boot the image. There is no output, looks like QEMU just hangs forever.
However when I use a kernel image from this img file https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2023-05-03/2023-05-03-raspios-bullseye-arm64.img.xz
it seems to be working fine.
The only difference I see is the image type:

Yocto: Image: Linux kernel ARM64 boot executable Image, little-endian, 4K pages
From downloaded img: kernel8.img: gzip compressed data, was "Image", last modified: Mon Apr  3 16:24:22 2023, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 22407680

The command I use to run QEMU:
qemu-system-aarch64 \
    -machine raspi3b \
    -cpu cortex-a53 \
    -append "rw earlyprintk loglevel=8 console=ttyAMA0,115200 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootdelay=1" \
    -dtb bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb \
    -drive id=disk0,file=core-image-minimal-raspberrypi3-64.rootfs.rpi-sdimg,if=sd,format=raw \
    -kernel kernel_file* \
    -m 1G -smp 4 \
    -nographic

*kernel_file - either Image or kernel8.img
Anyone has idea what am I doing wrong?
